# in android studio gradle task panel have no assembledebug task

Tags: android

gradle tasks list have no assembledebug and assemblerelease task when I build new project.

i mean that this is innormal

[image]

this is normal   [image]

why ? who can resolve this problem

Comment: you can type that as a command in terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in other -> assembleDebug :
[other -> assembleDebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12B3d.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't found that gradle task you just use it using terminal (command line) :

```
gradlew clean assembleDebug
gradlew clean assembleRelease
```

OR

```
gradlew clean assembleD
gradlew clean assembleR
```

Comment: above two picture  is different  first  picture is innormal  other is normal

Comment: i didn't get your answer